# Does Windows Phone 8.1 support multipe Segoe UI fonts

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

My setup is following: Windows Universal app (WinRt). I have use both VS 2013 and Blend 2013 for designing app.

I have notices that whenever I change font on `TextBox` in Visual Studio it has no effect on the actual font. I have also noticed that Blend always defaults to Segoe UI if I change the font. I wonder if fonts like Segoe UI Light are available on the Windows Phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Segoe UI Light, simply set the FontWeight property to Light.

If you're trying to do more customized things with text then yes you'll probably need to use custom fonts.

Comment: Aaa right! I thought that choosing Segoe UI Light would do the job. In fact you don't need to embed Segoe UI Light as it is already included on the phone!

Answer (score 0):

So after some research I found that Windows Phone 8.1 only supports Segoe UI and multiple other fonts out of the box and if you want to use other fonts apart from the ones shipped with the phone you will have to embed them. Here is a good article on how to do it: http://abnady.wordpress.com/2013/12/17/adding-custom-fonts-to-windows-store-app/
I think one of the drawbacks of using something like Helvetica is it will slow down slightly the startup time of your app. However I am not sure how significant is this.